# Problem with declaration of an array of pointers

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, declaration

When i execute this code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
 int (*x)[5];
printf("\nx = %u\nx+1 = %u\n&x = %u\n&x + 1 = %u",x,x+1,&x,&x+1);
}
```

This is the output in C or C++:

```
x = 134513520
x+1 = 134513540
&x = 3221191940
&x + 1 = 3221191944
```

Please explain. Also what is the difference between:

`int x[5]` and `int (*x)[5]` ?

Comment: [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28%2Ax%29%5B5%5D) is your friend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `int x[5]` is an array of 5 integers
- `int (*x)[5]` is a *pointer to* an array of 5 integers

When you increment a pointer, you increment by the size of the pointed to type. `x+1` is therefore `5*sizeof(int)` bytes larger than just `x` - giving the `8048370` and `8048384` hex values with a difference of 0x14, or 20.

`&x` is a pointer to a pointer - so when you increment it you add `sizeof(a pointer)` bytes - this gives the `bf9b08b4` and `bf9b08b8` hex values, with a difference of 4.

Answer (score 5):

1. `int x[5]` is an array of 5 ints
2. `int (*x)[5]` is a pointer to an array of 5 ints
3. `int* x[5]` is an array of 5 pointers to ints

Answer (score 4):

```
int (*x)[5];
```

declares a pointer to an array.

From the question title, you probably want

```
int* x[5];
```

instead, which declares an array of pointers.

```
int x[5];
```

declares a plain old array of `int`s.

Answer (score 3):

```
int x[5];
```

declares an array of five ints.

```
int (*x)[5];
```

declares a pointer to an array of 5 ints.

You might find [cdecl.org](http://www.cdecl.org/) useful.